# Expanding a single macro in C or C++ source files

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I have a large number of c++ source files that I'd like to transform by expanding a single function macro that I specify and leave all other preprocessing directives untouched. The arguments to the macro will, in general involve parens and braces and paren protected commas, so it does not seem straight forward to do this with sed and kin.

Update:
Our code has made heavy use of macros to generate boiler plate (eg helper code for swig). As we have better figured out how to do certain things, various of the macros no longer do anything terribly interesting (eg just declare some functions), and many people complain that they make the code harder to read. I'd like to expand the less interesting macros that expand to simple C++ code.

Comment: Can I ask why?  There may be a better strategy for whatever you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Without testing (therefor as comment not answer) .. you could probably run a global search and replace, changing `#include` to `//#include`, then run `gcc -E -DWHATEVER` and on the result reverse the initial search and replace ... alternatively write a limited parser or regexp ...

Comment: @johannes: oh thanks! I thought about running the pp but didn't thought about commenting the includes... :( But you're going to need to comment *all* pp statements for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

I did this sort of things by using regular expressions in python.  You can write a fairly short script to process a large number of files and run a few regular expressions on each of them.  Regular expressions would probably be the most time consuming part.

Comment: I've used that when the arguments are all simple (with no nested parens), but my understanding is that that matching the nested parenthesis is going to be difficult within a regex.

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing exactly what you are going to do but I think it should still be doable.

Comment: Definitely not doable... I need the compiler itself (or perhaps indeed m4) to do the macro expanding.

Comment: Yeah, this is, by definition, not possible using regular expressions, since parsing nested parens requires a context-free grammar. You can do it for simple expressions with no parens inside, but it would be difficult to know whether you've screwed up any complex expressions. That's why it would be ideal if the preprocessor (which knows how to parse macro expressions) could do it.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar need: get rid of (expand) those useless prototype-hiding macros used to deal with ancient pre-C89 compilers, while leaving everything else intact.

Example from `<stdio.h>`:

```
int     _EXFUN(vfprintf, (FILE *__restrict, const char *__restrict, __VALIST)
               _ATTRIBUTE ((__format__ (__printf__, 2, 0))));
int     _EXFUN(vprintf, (const char *, __VALIST)
               _ATTRIBUTE ((__format__ (__printf__, 1, 0))));
int     _EXFUN(vsprintf, (char *__restrict, const char *__restrict, __VALIST)
               _ATTRIBUTE ((__format__ (__printf__, 2, 0))));
int     _EXFUN(fgetc, (FILE *));
char *  _EXFUN(fgets, (char *__restrict, int, FILE *__restrict));
int     _EXFUN(fputc, (int, FILE *));
```

Here I needed to expand the macro `_EXFUN(name,proto)` to `name proto`. Note that some macro calls span more than one line.

The solution is to use a macro processor like `m4` because it is agnostic about #include directives and other macro processing (unlike `cpp` or `gcc -E`):

```
$ m4 '-D_EXFUN=$1$2' stdio.h
int     vfprintf(FILE *__restrict, const char *__restrict, __VALIST)
               _ATTRIBUTE ((__format__ (__printf__, 2, 0)));
int     vprintf(const char *, __VALIST)
               _ATTRIBUTE ((__format__ (__printf__, 1, 0)));
int     vsprintf(char *__restrict, const char *__restrict, __VALIST)
               _ATTRIBUTE ((__format__ (__printf__, 2, 0)));
int     fgetc(FILE *);
char *  fgets(char *__restrict, int, FILE *__restrict);
int     fputc(int, FILE *);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create a `undef.h` file
- Populate it with `#undef`'s for all the macros you want to NOT expand
- Include `extern int LandMarkSoYouCanFindThis;` as its last line
- For each file

  - Inject `#include "undef.h"` after the last include in a file.
  - run the file through `cpp`
  - use the `LandMark` to cut off everything from the includes
  - merge back into the original file.

You might be able to automate that last step by generating a patch from the difference between `#undef`ing just selected macros and `#undef`ing all macros.